# Does using a plugin to open a window in Garden FI match the experience of using a plugin in an FI's environment?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I was wondering if Garden FI is pretty much at parity with a real financial institution's environment. I was able to open a new window to the website of an FI that isn't the redirect_uri I provide to my developer portal using the plugin bridge module with this
`<a target="_blank" href="http://my_url"></a>`  element.

[This documentation](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/) says that you shouldn't be able to open other windows or it just isn't supported (I'd like some clarity if there's a difference in this situation too). Nonetheless I was able to open a window.

I make a plugin where in it, I call an API to grab some HTML to render an image that links back to the FI's FAQ or another FAQ elsewhere.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://my_url"></a>
```

Clicking this image sends me to a new page that isn't reflected in my redirect_uri list on the dev portal. I expected this not to work according to [this documentation](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/).

How different is Garden FI from an actual FI and can I open windows/tabs that aren't the redirect URI?

Thanks team, this is important for me developing a cool plugin for my client and setting expectations.

Comment: The _Garden_ demo institution runs production Banno code (but as named, it's a _demo_ institution) so it's as real as it gets in terms of behavior. The behavior you are seeing is expected.

Comment: You're on the right track with using the [Plugin Bridge](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/) to open different links (as opposed to using a configured primary action button, which has limited functionality). I see that the docs as-written are confusing, so I've taken a note to get the docs updated to clarify that the use case you have in mind is indeed a _valid_ use case supported by the Plugin Framework.

Comment: Cool, I see the updates to the docs, it all makes sense to me now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Garden* demo institution runs production Banno code (but as named, it's a *demo* institution) so it's as real as it gets in terms of behavior. The behavior you are seeing is expected.

You're on the right track by using the [Plugin Bridge](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/).

We've updated the [Restrictions](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/) page to clarify that opening a new window is supported via the Plugin Bridge's handling of embedded web browser links.